# How to input chinese characters in php cli?

Tags: php

The chinese characters can be displayed and inputted on my LXTerminal.

```
root@hwy:/home/debian8# 中文    \\now to input chinese characters on my LXTerminal,it means  chinese characters can be inputted.
bash: 中文: command not found   \\ bash react the  chinese characters on my LXTerminal,it means  chinese characters can be displayed.
```

The chinese characters can be inputted and displayed on my python shell.
[image]
Now let's enter into php cli(or say php shell)

[image]

[image]
The chinese characters disappeared when to click enter key.
it means that chinese characters can be displayed but can not be inputted on php cli mode.
How to make the chinese characters can be inputted  on php cli mode?
And it is a verified fact that chinese characters can't be pasted into php cli too.
Maybe some mbstring attributes will be edited in /etc/php5/cli/php.ini?

Thank to bwoebi .Three facts added to go on my research.
1.  Versions of libreadline and libedit.

```
root@hwy:/home/debian8# find /  -name   'libreadline*'
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6.3
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6


root@hwy:/home/debian8# find /  -name   'libedit*'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libedit.so.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libedit.so.2.0.51
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/libedit2
```

2.root@hwy:/home/debian8# ldd "$(which php)"

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd35e5c000)
libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007ff98ac68000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007ff98aa4d000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007ff98a836000)
libonig.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libonig.so.2 (0x00007ff98a5cc000)
libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007ff98a1d0000)
libssl.so.1.0.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00007ff989f6f000)
libdb-5.3.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdb-5.3.so (0x00007ff989bae000)
libqdbm.so.14 => /usr/lib/libqdbm.so.14 (0x00007ff989961000)
libbz2.so.1.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0 (0x00007ff989751000)
libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007ff9894e3000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007ff9892db000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007ff988fda000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ff988dd6000)
libnsl.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007ff988bbe000)
libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007ff988857000)
libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007ff98860c000)
libkrb5.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007ff988338000)
libk5crypto.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007ff988107000)
libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007ff987f03000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff987b58000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ff98793b000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ff98ae9f000)
liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007ff987718000)
libkrb5support.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007ff98750c000)
libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007ff987308000)
```

3.Chinese characters on php7 -a
php7 was installed as
http://www.tecmint.com/install-and-compile-php-7-on-centos-7-and-debian-8/
Chinese characters can be displayed and inputed on `php7 -a`.

There is a new discovery!
It is the readline library on php7.

```
php7 -i |grep Readline
Readline Support => enabled
Readline library => 6.3
```

It is the EditLine wrapper on php5.

```
php -i |grep Readline
Readline Support => enabled
Readline library => EditLine wrapper
```

The problem is in half-solved status .
How to make my php5 to use Readline library 6.3 as php7 do ?
I don't want to compile my php5 again ,just to change the library?
Today i compile php5 in my virtualbox with command :

```
./configure \
--prefix=/usr/local/php5.6 \
--with-config-file-path=/usr/local/php5.6/etc \
--with-readline
```

Chinese characters can be inputted and displayed on `php -a` interactive mode.
It is unwise to remove current php5 and compile everything from the beginning.

```
find / -name 'readline.so*'
/usr/lib/php5/20131226/readline.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.1.0/readline.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libguilereadline-v-18.so.18
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libguilereadline-v-18.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libguilereadline-v-18.so.18.0.0
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/readline.x86_64-linux-gnu.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6.3
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6
```

Maybe to  enable /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6.3 ,how to make it work for my php5?

Comment: Why your command is named in chinese?

Comment: I want to verify that chinese characters can be inputed and displayed on my LXTerminal.

Comment: I don't understand how the fact that your shell or terminal is transforming your chinese character inputs has anything to do with PHP? PHP isn't handling the input on the terminal, your shell is.

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Answer (score 1):

`php -a` uses either libreadline or libedit as underlying libraries.

Inside the `readline_shell_run()` function in ext/readline/readline.c, PHP calls the `readline()` library function. So the problem doesn't lie in PHP itself, but in the library used.

On my OS X terminal [libedit 3.0.0] it works fine, pasting and passing to CLI.

So, to figure out the problem, what are you using libreadline? or libedit? (check version and library used with `ldd "$(which php)"`) Research whether the version of libedit or libreadline your PHP installation uses has known bugs with the encoding of the terminal you're using.

If there are newer versions of the libraries, you might want trying to install these instead and check whether the issue is gone.

Answer (score 0):

use `LD_PRELOAD=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6 php -a` to make php use libreadline instead of libedit wrapper. This can handle UTF-8 input correctly.
you might need to set `export LANG=C.UTF-8` to make it work.

You can verify LD_PRELOAD effect with `LD_PRELOAD=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6 php -i|grep Readline`